# Please help me to prove this statement

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that 
$$(3x^2 −7x−2012)(3x^2 −7x−2011)(3x^2 −7x−2010)(3x^2 
−7x−2009)+1$$
is equal to a number squared.

I first thought to multiply all, but I was stucked with big numbers, so I quit. Thx for the answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Observe that the difference between any two consecutive multiplicands is $1$

Put $3x^2 −7x−2010=a$

$$\implies(a-2)(a-1)a(a+1)+1$$
$$=(a-2)(a+1)(a-1)a+1$$
$$=(a^2-a-2)(a^2-a)+1$$
$$=(a^2-a)^2-2(a^2-a)+1=(a^2-a-1)^2$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried it and succesfully find the answer. :D

Comment: @Pebrianto, Nice to hear that